# nested BEGIN-END blocks in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {print FILE}
{printf "Part\t\tStart\t\tEnd"
printf "%s %-6s %-6d",Part1,1,$end1
printf "%s %-6d %-6d",Part2,$start2,$end2}
END {printf "total records:%d", $tot}' >meta.txt
```

This is my code and is not working. It is a part of a shell script, all the variables are computed in other part of script.
My I/P files are tables, and I have to find out no. of records in them and dispay the results in a file in the form of a table like

```
File   Start  End
File1  1      205
file2  206    417
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are shell variables, you need to pass them into the AWK script:

```
awk -v "start2=$start2" -v "end1=$end1" -v "end2=$end2" -v "tot=$tot" 'BEGIN {print FILE}
    {printf "Part\t\tStart\t\tEnd"
    printf "%s %-6s %-6d", Part1, 1, end1
    printf "%s %-6d %-6d", Part2, start2, end2}
    END {printf "total records:%d", tot}' >meta.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one BEGIN and END block in awk. I actually don't really understanding what you are trying to do. So I expect you to show more examples. however, to create a file table in awk, you can do it in the BEGIN block

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  print "field1\tfield2\n"
  ...
  print "one\ttwo"
  ...
}' > outputfile.txt
```

if you have an input file to process, and the table contents comes from this input file

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  print "field1\tfield2\n"
}
{
  ...
  print "one\ttwo"
  ...
}END{
  print "so some final stuff here"
}' inputfile > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{
  print "field1\tfield2\n"
  ...
  print "one\ttwo"
  ...
}' > outputfile.txt its not working

Comment: why don't you show what you are trying to do with example input files, and show the output you want to see. Let's put aside any code that you may have for later.

Comment: I have I/P files, I want to find out their no of records and output the no of records in the form of a table like                     File  star  End                                                       File1 1     213

Comment: You can have as many `BEGIN`, `END` and main blocks as you want and they will be grouped in the order they are found (and executed at the appropriate time as if there were one of each type).